# Time complexity and recurrence relation for maximum number of A’s using given four keys

Tags: recurrence-relations, computational-complexity, recursion, recursive-algorithms

I am wondering if someone can help me figure out the recurrence relation for [maximum number of A’s using given four keys problem](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-print-maximum-number-of-a-using-given-four-keys/). The following is the code fragment

```
int maxCharacterFor(int N) {
   if (N <= 6) return N;

   int maxChars = 0;   
   for (int b=N-3; b>=1; b--) 
        maxChars = Math.max(maxChars, (N-b-1)*maxCharacterFor(b));

   return maxChars;
}
```

I know it's definitely exponential and feels like very close to O(N!), but I am not sure if the following recurrence relation is correct or not. And how to analyze its run-time.

$$
T(n) =\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-3} T(k) + O(n)
$$

Comment: A small correction: the max is of $O(n)$ which must be added to the sum.

Comment: So if you've stored the previous results (smell of dynamic programming) then you're left with computing the max only which is O(n) (given multiplications etc, are small enough of O(1) though!), otherwise, pretty horrible exponential!

Comment: @EhsanM.Kermani thanks for pointing it out. Just updated it. I am wondering with dynamic programming wouldn't it be O(N^2) even though we are just looking up precomputed result, but for each cell we still need O(N) time to find the max, correct ?

Comment: you're right! The whole complexity would be O(n^2), grid like approach.

Comment: The $+O(n)$ is redundant, since you already have a sum that is $O(n)$.  Also, there are no $O(n)$ calculations in the algorithm except for the sum, just a few $O(\log n)$ ones.  Also, it is not really correct to use $n$ as the parameter of the runtime, since the size of the input is $\log n$, you should use $m = \log n$ and describe the runtime in terms of $m$.

Comment: @DanielV the $O(n)$ is for the max of $n-3$ already computed not the sum (this is recursive)! why're saying the size of input is $\log n?$